# Advice on controlling an unknown dim-able 12V LED

Tags: led, mosfet, dimming

I have been controlling "5050" RGB LED strips from the GPIO of a Raspberry pi with a simple circuit using mosfets. This is the guide that I followed:

https://dordnung.de/raspberrypi-ledstrip/

It works well, however I need also to use miniature single coloured directional LEDs. I found these LED spotlights which are also 12V and dim-able:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32956926521.html?spm=a2g0s.8937460.0.0.40142e0eI4rsrU

An apology here: I know very little about electronics (but can solder up simple circuits).

Will the same basic mosfet circuitry work for these spots? If not, any way of testing for what will work?

This is the only technical information given:

LEDIARY 12V Mini LED Spot Downlights Dimmable Lamp Set Remote Control Ceiling Recessed 1.5W 27mm Cut Hole Silvery Cabinet Lights
1.Material: Aluminum+PC+ABS+ Epistar LED
2.Lamp Size: Diameter 31mm, Height 22mm, Cutting Hole Size: 27mm
3.Input: 85V-265V for the adapter  (12V for the lamp.)
4.Real Watt:1.5W for one lamp
5.Lumen: 100lm  for one lamp
6.Body Color: Silvery
7.Lighing Color: Cold White/ Warm White
8.Controller parameter: RF controller(can control lamp across  the wall or ceiling), and can make stepless control (dim the brightness smoothly).
9.Control distance: 5-10m
10. Power for controller: 3 pieces AAA battery ( Not included, please purchase in local shop.)

The simple IRLZ34N mosfet circuit that I am using for the led strips:

[image]

Comment: Aliexpress parts are notorious for being poorly documented and not having datasheets/other accurate specifications. If you want to go ahead with this part, you may end up finding out that it's incompatible, and without a datasheet, we would also only be able to guess at how it works.

Comment: Please also upload the relevant images into your question so we don't have to follow links and the question still makes sense when the links die.

Comment: I added the limited technical data they have. I'm not able to download the photo of the product. Included a picture of the breadboard circuit that I'm currently using

Comment: Do you want to control all 6 at the same time or each lamp individually?

Comment: Each individually, but it could be done in pairs. I may only need two or perhaps 3 or 4 spotlights for each Pi and circuit used

Comment: The link shows set of LED lights with controller and remote. But you can buy only lights. Same way to control it like strips.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I would ditch the controller. So could these be used with the mosfets that I've been using? If you have any links with the spots alone, without controller, please send. I couldn't find ones without that say they are dimmable.